# Font-awesome <i> tags auto-generated in JSP

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, font-awesome

I'm trying to include *SB-Admin2* theme using a *Spring Roo* generated project (using bootstrap, tiles and JSP)  but something is going wrong. I have icons corresponding to `fa-search` font-awesome tags that are displayed on the page.

It seems, that they have been generated when JSP tiles have been processed because they do not appear in my code.

```
      <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."></input>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>

                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" ignore="true" /> 

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
```

File "menu.tagx" is :

```
<c:if test="${empty render or render}">
    <li>
        <jsp:doBody />
    </li>

</c:if>
```

And file "items.tagx" is:

```
<c:if test="${empty label}">
  <spring:message code="menu_item_${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substringAfter(id,'_'))}_label" var="label" htmlEscape="false" />
</c:if>

<c:if test="${not empty messageCode}">
  <spring:message code="${messageCode}" var="label" arguments="${label}" htmlEscape="false" />
</c:if>

<li>
  <spring:url value="${url}" var="menu_item_url"/>
  <a href="${menu_item_url}" title="${fn:escapeXml(label)}">
    <c:out value="${label}"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

Generated code in Chrome inspector is:

```
    <div role="navigation" class="navbar-default sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="side-menu" class="nav">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                    <input placeholder="Search..." class="form-control" type="text">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </li>
                <div version="2.0" id="menu">
                <li><h2><i class="fa fa-search">Party</i></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-search"><a title="Create new Party" href="/demo/partys?form">Create new Party</a></i></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-search"><a title="List all Partys" href="/demo/partys?page=1&amp;size=10">List all Partys</a></i></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-search"><a title="Find by Last Name" href="/demo/partys?find=ByLastName&amp;form&amp;page=1&amp;size=10">Find by Last Name</a></i></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where do the `<i class="fa fa-search">` elements come from? How to remove them?

Thank you very much for your help. Denis

Comment: You say your last block is from Chrome inspector; what is the actual rendered HTML for the relevant elements? (i.e. Ctrl+U) This would allow confirming whether the change is performed on the back- or the front-end.

Comment: <i class="fa fa-search"> - do NOT appear in HTML code (using Ctrl + U)

Comment: In this case you should be able to find the JavaScript code that's changing this by using [the advice outlined here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25191851/1240557). Knowing which script and where makes the changes would be hopefully enough to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your tips ! I have finally found where it comes from...

If you don't put content (for instance a comment) between opening and closing tags processed by font-awesome CSS, parser will generate icons in front of all text areas displayed.

To avoid this, you must properly declare  tags in your JSP like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-search"><!--  Some content --></i>
```

And not:

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Hope this help.